# overloading operator<< to output object members without using friend function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend-function

I am refreshing cpp after a long gap, trying to understand the operator overloading methods. 
I tried to overload "operator<<" to output members of object. but I am unable to do so without using friend function. I am looking for a method without using friend function.

here is my class def:

```
class Add{
private:
int x;

public:
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, Add const& rhs); //Method 1
void operator<<(ostream& ostr);                //Method 2
};
```

functions implementations

```
//Method 1
ostream& operator<<(ostream &ostr, Add const& rhs)
{
    ostr<<rhs.x;

return ostr;
}

//Method 2
void Add::operator<<(ostream& ostr)
{
    cout<<" using operator<< \n";
    ostr<<x;
}
```

calls from the main function

```
cout<<Obj_Add;  //calls the Method 1

Obj_Add<<cout;  //calls the Method 2
```

Now my question is, I would like to achieve the Method 1 type calls without using the friend function. But do not know, it is possible or not in cpp. I have tried few implementation but all are gives me compile errors. Please help me to understand the point i'm missing here.

Comment: What's the reason for wanting to avoid friend functions for this?

Comment: @aix: Always prefer non-member, non-friend functions for additional operations. The smaller your interface into the real world, the lesser the places you have to worry about when changing something.

Comment: Xeo: *non member, non friend* discards both alternatives, so aix's question still stands: why? This is precisely the reason for friendship in the first place.

Comment: @aix: if we remove friend, the compiler want the function to be decleared with one parameter eventhough it is in public to class. Why this restriction?

Comment: @chinnagaja: Are you aware that a `friend` declaration declares a non-member function? This means that if you remove `friend` you must also move the declaration outside of the class body to keep the meaning of the declaration the same.

Comment: @charles: yes i understood the friend rules. But I would like to know why the compiler is not accepting a operator overload function with two arguments instead of 'this' with one argument.

Comment: this answer clarifies me more clearly. for your Ref. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html#faq-14.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have public accessor functions in your class, or a `stream`-like one, you don't need the friendship with `operator<<`:

```
// v1
class foo{
public:
  int data() const{ return _data; }
private:
  int _data;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, foo const& f){
  return o << f.data();
}

// v2
class foo{
public:
  void stream_to(std::ostream& o){
    o << _data;
  }
private:
  int _data;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, foo const& f){
  f.stream_to(o);
  return o;
}
```

v2 has the added benefit of allowing `stream_to` to be a `virtual` function, which is helpful for polymorphic base-classes, so you don't need to reimplement `operator<<` for every derived class, only `stream_to`.

Comment: I would avoid the first option: opening the implementation details to *all* code to avoid opening access to *one* friend is not such a good idea (it could be worse, making the field public, but the fact that it is not the worst alternative does not make it the *best* option)

Comment: @David: Well, I only adhered to the "client"'s specifications: no friends. ;)

Comment: v2 seems a good option. but without friend we cannot achieve cout<<obj calls with the class member functions. Is there any specific reason for not doing this.

Comment: @chinnagaja: What exactly do you mean? You can call `std::cout << my_foo;` just fine with both versions.

Comment: @Xeo: yes I agree. but the function is not a member function of foo. if you make it as member in public the compiler throws error. how to achieve this call to a member function of foo. I feel method-2 in my question is safe than friend or non-member function but call to that function is should be in reverse order (obj<<cout)

Comment: @chinnagaja: You can't. If you make `operator<<` a member function, then the left-hand side (`X` in `X << Y`) needs to be of your class type. That's why it needs to be a free function (possibly a friend). How would you possibly distinguish between `X << Y` and `Y << X`, where `X` is your class type?

Comment: @xeo: now I understood the need of free or friend func in operator<< if we use other than our class objects (cout). Thanks for helping me to understand.

Comment: @Xeo: Why reference to ostream is passed when overloading << operator? Why I can't write (ostream o,foo const & f in the argument?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with a getter of x.

if the operator<< is not friend, it can not access the member x

```
class Add {
    private:
        int x;

    public:
        int getX() { return x; }
};

//Method 1
ostream& operator<<(ostream &ostr, Add const& rhs)
{
    //ostr<<rhs.x;       //Fail: x is private

    ostr << rhs.getX();  //Good

    return ostr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid having the operator function as friend if you have some other means of getting `x` from the object.

```
class Foo
{
private:
    int bar;

public:
    int get_bar() const { return bar; }
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Foo &foo)
{
    os << foo.get_bar();
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible unless you add some mechanism to get `x` out, e.g. a `public`

```
// in the class
int get_x() const { return x; }
```

or a different mechanism to print an object

```
// outside the class
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Add const &obj)
{
    obj.print(out);
    return out;
}
```